# strictBindCallApply not playing nicely with generic argument

Tags: typescript, typescript-generics

Consider the following (admittedly contrived) code snippet:

```
export function test<T>(this: { property: T }) {
  return this.property;
}

class MyClass {
  property: '';
  constructor() {
    const r = test.call(this);
  }
}
```

You will note that the type of `r` is `unknown`.

**Does anyone know if this is a shortcoming of the `strictBindCallApply` setting or if I am doing something wrong?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems you've run into an actual problem with `strictCallApply`.

As far as I can see, it matches up with the [**Caveats** section](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-3-2.html#caveats) from this feature's announcement:

> ## Caveats
>
> [...]
>
> Additionally, [another caveat](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/pull/27028#issuecomment-429334450) of this new functionality is that due to certain limitations, bind, call, and apply can’t yet fully model generic functions or functions that have overloads. When using these methods on a generic function, type parameters will be substituted with the empty object type ({}), and when used on a function with overloads, only the last overload will ever be modeled.

The link from the announcement leads to a comment by **mattmccutchen** from 12 Oct 2018 on the pull request for the feature that demonstrates the problem the following way:

> It looks like the new feature doesn't work well for generic or overloaded functions. Silly example:
>
> ```
> function foo<T>(name: string, arg: T): T {
>     console.log(name);
>     return arg;
> }
>
> // Type of `fooResult` is `{}`. :(
> let fooResult = foo.bind(undefined, "Matt")("TypeScript");
>
> function bar(name: string, arg: number): number;
> function bar(name: string, arg: string): string;
> function bar(name: string, arg: string | number) {
>     console.log(name);
>     return (typeof arg === "number") ? arg + 1 : arg + "1";
> }
>
> // Error: Argument of type '5' is not assignable to parameter of type 'string'.
> let barResult = bar.bind(undefined, "Matt")(5);
> ```

And here it is a [Playground link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/?ssl=1&ssc=1&pln=10&pc=2#code/GYVwdgxgLglg9mABMOcA8AVAfACjAQwFsBTALkQGcoAnGMAcwBpF9r7yMBKDxAbwFgAUIhGIICCnAA2xAHRS49PEWKcA3ENGJqxKCGpJW9DYIC+QoQHpLiDAE8ADsURxgiAAYo4AJWIUQUlDuiDAUHrym7rKIpDhCMlDIqL7+gYgAvElwsgBGdAAmOOD5xMB0xPnMAEQAsvhQUFWcOFX2TgDKELQOjeoWgqCQsAiIOazKJORUtAzMRuRgIIQ5xNTciIvLqyaD0PBIY9QTZJQ0dEwsbFNnDOvT5zvgeyOHx9czF-OnH4gAPhtLFZrPiaUTiMCSGTyRTHPrCUQ6PQGRA4KCOYiuS70DLpTJVTZApqIAD8WMQAGpEABGGJkylVKlVEzmQRWGwAUWo1Dg1HIAEE2EtiGBEpi0U5EAByACskpCYTAcES+AoFBg9AIORkiCgcEQDlYKigqxcbnFzkl9wYktk8V0o1YKQCiUyh1yBSKYBKZTAFWqdQaTRw0vUQA)

Currently in version 3.9.2 `fooResult` is determined to be `unknown`. This matches up with what you are seeing. I cannot currently find where that was changed but it is was changed in a later version.